# I have made a square image round with CSS, however I can't seem to make it responive

Tags: css

I am making a profile page and have turned a square image into a circle using the CSS code below:

```
.circular {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background-image: url('./images/profile.jpg');
background-size: cover;
display: block;
border-radius: 125px;
-webkit-border-radius: 125px;
-moz-border-radius: 125px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -150px;
}
```

However I am struggling to make this responsive within the header portion of my page, any ideas how I could have rounded corners and make the image scale at the same time?

Thanks!

Comment: That's really **BAD** idea to use `px` while making responsive design !! So you should user percentage instead !!

Comment: If you have breakpoints you need to include it to them specially the width and height properties. and use %

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest like already mentioned to avoid fixed `px` values and instead use percentages.

Another approach (if applicable in your case) could be the use of screenbased responsive styling like:

```
@media screen and (min-width:960px) {
    .circular {
        /* ... */
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:1440px) {
    .circular {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

With that you can ensure that you have fixed transition points when you resize your design/image.

Comment: I think this is the way I am going to go! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following.

Just ensure that the parent container is of reasonable width, because .circular will take all of its width.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px; /* for example... */
}
.circular {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circular"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, if the other way doesn't work great I will try this! Thanks for your help.